# Как сделать ссылку на Google Maps через изображение?

Tags: google-maps-api

Когда пользователь кликает на изображение (прим. прикрепленное изображение), у него открывается Google Maps уже с представленными координатами. Как можно такое реализовать?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помещаете картинку в `ImageView`. У `ImageView` обрабатываете событие клика.

В обработчике события запускаете Google Maps через `Intent`, передавая в него соответствующие параметры.